# Issues starting Postgres server

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to go through the book "7 Databases in 7 Weeks" and I'm completely stuck at starting a Postgres server.

My current issue is that when I run `pg_ctl start` I get the following error:

```
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2013-06-12 17:18:24 PDT
LOG:  invalid magic number 0000 in log file 0, segment 1, offset 0
LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record
LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record
PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
LOG:  startup process (PID 1454) was terminated by signal 6: Abort trap
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

I have no idea how to go about fixing this. I'm running PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on Mountain Lion 10.8.3.

Comment: How did you installed the DB server?

Comment: More important, what did you do prior startup? The error is that it is missing a WAL.

Comment: @dezso Installed with Homebrew. I had some issues with postgres finding the pgsql_socket and followed the first answer in this post to get it up and running, but that doesn't seem like it has to do with the error: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21587/postgresql-is-running-locally-but-i-cannot-connect-why

Comment: @JimmyStenke: I had installed with the graphical installer from www.enterprisedb.com first, but had issues so used the uninstall app and then used Homebrew. The Homebrew install had the issues in my previous comment so I uninstalled the brew and then reinstalled the brew a couple times. When I finally got it working, the DB from the previous stall was still in /usr/local/var/postgres/ so I just used that.

Comment: OK, I just deleted the old DB folder and recreated it, and it works. Thanks for pointing me in the right direcion @JimmyStenke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per JimmyStenke's suggestion, I realized I had a DB initialized from a previous install, and it seems that was causing the error. I deleted it and initialized a new DB.